# Is the sequence $a_{n} = \frac {1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + .... +\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ Cauchy?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

**First:**

I tried substituting natural numbers for $n$ to calculate the consecutive terms of the sequence and then see the difference between their values and I found that the difference is decreasing for large values of $n$ (not very large because I am calculating by my hand)so I concluded that it is a Cauchy sequence but unfortunately when I looked at the hint for solving this problem I found it to be:
"Prove that $a_{2n} - a_{n} \geq n * \frac{2n}{(2n +1)^2} \geq \frac{2}{9}$" so I concluded that it is not Cauchy. So can anyone tell me please why testing by numbers sometimes lead to wrong values and when it is preferable to use this test?

**Second:**

If $a_{n} = \frac {1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + .... +\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$, Does $a_{2n} =  \frac {1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{3^2} + .... +\frac{2n}{(2n+1)^2}$? because I am confused what it equals.

I hope my question fulfills the requirements of a good question, if no please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I tried substituting natural numbers for n to calculate the consecutive terms of the sequence and ...found that the difference is decreasing"

It doesn't matter if the difference between *consecutive* terms get smaller (and converge to zero).  The terms $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ may get minisculely close together but in all the terms further down $a_{10^{\text{500 hundred quadrillion zillion oogleplex}}}$   can still be huge.

What does matter is that as $N$ gets large then the difference between *any* two terms (*not* just consecutive terms).  To be Cauchy $a_n$ and $a_{10^{\text{500 hundred quadrillion zillion oogleplex}}}$ must be close together if $n, 10^{\text{500 hundred quadrillion zillion oogleplex}}$ are both greater than $N$.

So it doesn't matter of $a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac {n+1}{(n+2)^2} \to 0$.  We need to have as $a_m - a_n = \frac {n+1}{(n+2)^2} +  \frac {n+2}{(n+3)^2}+ \frac {n+3}{(n+4)^2}+ ....... + \frac {m}{(m+1)^2}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  As $a_m - a_n =   \frac {n+1}{(n+2)^2} +  \frac {n+2}{(n+3)^2}+ \frac {n+3}{(n+4)^2}+ ....... + \frac {m}{(m+1)^2}$ may have many, many,many terms this is a *very* tall order.

And it doesn't hold true.

$a_{2n} - a_n = \frac {n+1}{(n+2)^2} + \frac {n+2}{(n+3)^2} + ..... + \frac {2n}{(2n+1)^2} >$

$\frac {2n}{(2n+1)}^2 +\frac {2n}{(2n+1)}^2+.... + \frac {2n}{(2n+1)}^2 =$

$n*\frac {2n}{(2n+1)}^2 = \frac {2n^2}{4n^2 + 4n + 1} >$

$\frac {2n^2}{4n^2 + 4n^2 + n^2} =\frac {2n^2}{9n^2}= \frac 29$.

This means you will always be able to find to terms that are at least $\frac 29$ apart.  No matter how large we take $N$ we can always find $n > N$ and $2n > N$ so that $a_{2n} - a_n > \frac 29$.  So it is not true that the difference of *any* two terms goes to $0$.

So the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: So helpful answer thank you so much :)

Comment: I know that you increased the denominator so we decreased the fraction but for the numerator why must 2n be less than n +1 or n+2 or n+3 .....

Comment: As $\frac {k}{(k+1)^2} > \frac {k+1}{(k+2)^2}$ for all $k \ge 1$.  Although $k+1 > k$ then denominator simply grows at a faster rate to compensate for it.  If you take the ratio $\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k} = $$\frac {\frac {k+1}{(k+2)^2}}{\frac k{(k+1)^2}} =$$\frac{(k+1)(k+1)^2} {k(k+2)^2} = $$\frac {k^3 + 3k^2 + k + 1}{k^3 + 4k^2 + 4k} < 1$.  So the $a_k$ are decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy sequence requires $|a_m-a_n| \to 0$ when $n$ and $m$ both $\to \infty$.  So the note that for $m=2n$ it does not $\to 0$ shows that the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: Is my formula to $a_{2n}$ written correctly?

Comment: The formula  for $a_{2n}$ is correct.   It doesn't matter what it equals.  The important point is that $|a_{2n}-a_n|$ does not $\to 0$.

Comment: because I need to prove the formula in the given hint by induction ......this is why I am asking you if it is correct.

Comment: Your first question is why use Cauchy?   Your example illustrates why: $a_{2^k}={a_{2^k}}-a_{2^{k-1}}+a_{2^{k-1}}-a_{2^{k-2}}+.... \gt \frac{2}{9}k \to \infty$.

Comment: My last comment might be useful if you want to use induction (on k, not on n).  Is the induction to show $a_{2n}-a_n$ is bounded away from $0$?

Comment: but why the $k$ is a power of the 2 in your before last comment?

Comment: The basic idea is that your induction steps go from n to 2n to 4n, etc., because you are using $|a_{2n}-a_n|\gt \frac{2}{9}$ for each step.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$(n+1)^2 \le 4n^2 \iff n+1 \le 2n \iff n \ge 1$$

so $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)^2} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{4k^2} = \frac14 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$$

Therefore $(a_n)_n$ is unbounded so it cannot be Cauchy.

Comment: but I need to proof it by definition

Comment: @hopefully Can you show by definition that Cauchy sequences are necessarily bounded?

Comment: supposed to know but I think the above hint is given to precise $\epsilon$ , n and m